# Azure stream analytics query to convert datetime field to separate date & time field

Tags: azure, azure-stream-analytics

Here is my datetime field: system.timestamp with value `2019-10-22T08:00:22.4994430Z`

I am looking for query in Azure Stream Analytics to convert datetime from one field (system.timestamp) to 2 fields (NewDate and NewTime).

NewDate would become 2019-10-22, NewTime would become 08:00

I have tried many queries but non of them work as expected, the closest was:

```
SELECT DATETIMEFROMPARTS(DATEPART(year,[EventEnqueuedUtcTime]),DATEPART(month,[EventEnqueuedUtcTime]),DATEPART(day,[EventEnqueuedUtcTime]),00,00,00,00) AS newdate
```

But result is `2019-10-22T00:00:00.0000000Z`

There are still time with 0s and have not gone further for time

```
SELECT
    DATETIMEFROMPARTS(DATEPART(year,[EventEnqueuedUtcTime]),DATEPART(month,[EventEnqueuedUtcTime]),DATEPART(day,[EventEnqueuedUtcTime]),00,00,00,00)
AS newdate
INTO
    table1
FROM
    esp32
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to convert it to NVarChar. Below is the example of how you can make it be in the following format yyyy-mm-dd:

```
SELECT
Concat(DateName(yyyy, SourceTimestamp),'-',
CAST(CASE 
              WHEN LEN(CAST(DATEPART(mm,SourceTimestamp) AS NVARCHAR(MAX))) > 1
                 THEN CAST(DATEPART(mm,SourceTimestamp) AS NVARCHAR(MAX))
              ELSE Concat('0', CAST(DATEPART(mm,SourceTimestamp) AS NVARCHAR(MAX)))
        END AS NVARCHAR(MAX)),
'-',
CAST(CASE 
              WHEN LEN(CAST(DATEPART(dd,SourceTimestamp) AS NVARCHAR(MAX))) > 1
                 THEN CAST(DATEPART(dd,SourceTimestamp) AS NVARCHAR(MAX))
              ELSE Concat('0', CAST(DATEPART(dd,SourceTimestamp) AS NVARCHAR(MAX)))
        END AS NVARCHAR(MAX))) as NewDate

INTO
    table1
FROM
    esp32
```

A similar example you can apply to get a date in the format hh:mm.

**Update**

You can add UDF function as another alternative solution that would return the value in the desired format. For example your NewDate UDF would look like(and returns string):

```
// Sample UDF which returns sum of two values.
function main(arg1) {
   'use strict';
   var date = new Date(arg1);
   var yearString = date.getFullYear().toString();
   var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
   var day = date.getDate();
   var monthString = month < 10 ? "0" + month.toString() : month.toString();
   var dayString = day < 10 ? "0" + day.toString() : day.toString();

   return yearString + '-' + monthString + '-' + dayString;
}
```

And query that is using this function:

For time - NewTime function:

```
function main(arg1) {
   'use strict';
   var date = new Date(arg1);
   var hour = date.getHours();
   var minutes = date.getMinutes();
   var hoursString = hour < 10 ? "0" + hour.toString() : hour.toString();
   var minutesString = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes.toString() : minutes.toString();

   return hoursString + ":" + minutesString;
}
```

And Query:

```
SELECT UDF.NewDate(system.Timestamp), UDF.NewTime(system.Timestamp)
INTO table1
FROM esp32
```

Comment: thanks @kgalic, UDF is working great, can you help to share UDF for time, example 14:25 (i.e. HH:MM)

Comment: updated question, have a look, but it is really similar to the date function ;)

Comment: thanks kgalic, working just fine, finally two solution how to achieve date / time split..

Answer (score 0):

Azure Stream Analytics only knows the DateTime data type (including both, date and time): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/stream-analytics-query/data-types-azure-stream-analytics

However, you can use `DATEPART()` function to achieve want you want: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/stream-analytics-query/datepart-azure-stream-analytics

You can use various versions of `DATEPART()` and construct the results into strings.

Comment: Thanks @silent, i tried that as you said and i was able to make it to split and create new rows, how can I just put this together as a string:   
SELECT DATEPART (year, DATEADD(hour,2,EventEnqueuedUtcTime)) AS year,
    DATEPART (month, DATEADD(hour,2,EventEnqueuedUtcTime)) AS month,
    DATEPART (week, DATEADD(hour,2,EventEnqueuedUtcTime)) AS week,
    DATEPART (day, DATEADD(hour,2,EventEnqueuedUtcTime)) AS day

Comment: just use concat()?! https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/stream-analytics-query/concat-azure-stream-analytics

Comment: thanks @silent, just for others looking for solution: `SELECT
    CONCAT(DATEPART(hour, EventEnqueuedUtcTime), ':', DATEPART(minute, EventEnqueuedUtcTime)) AS Time,
    CONCAT(DATEPART(year, EventEnqueuedUtcTime), '-', DATEPART(month, EventEnqueuedUtcTime), '-', DATEPART(day, EventEnqueuedUtcTime)) AS Date
INTO
    table1
FROM
    device1`

Comment: One more question @silent, I found one complication with DATEPART, it is not having leading 0 i.e. "20:5" instead of "20:05" :( Any solution to add leading 0 ?